# What datetime format would you use in your JSON API?

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, web

Whould it be UNIX timestamp format or some ISO?

**UPDATED**
Considering that API consumer are more programming languages. (Java, C++, Javascript)

**UPDATED2**
And what about this problem? http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/nakul/archive/2011/02/10/unix-timestamp-and-the-year-2038-problem.aspx And what about dates before 1970?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ISO standard. It's a standard for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the destination language and your comfort with it. for example, in php I just use the epoch (UNIX time stamp) since you can easily get a date from

```
$epoch = time();
date("l F jS, Y",$epoch);
// "Wednesday January 18th, 2012" if variable was now();
```

and i find it easier to do comparisons and modifications with it as well using `time()`, `mktime()` etc...

Comment: You can't parse dates in PHP? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
There are multiple languages.

Comment: -1 The whole point of a good (web) API is that it should be language agnostic.